# Can a web_link be shared with API v2.0?

Tags: box-api

You can create a web_link file on a Box Folder.
The web_link can be shared via Box UI, but I could not do it with API v2.0:

Neither: 
**PUT /files/{file id}**              nor
**PUT /web_links/{file id}**
worked. Both returned HTTP 404 when used with the id of the web_link.

Is this supported or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think shared items in the API docs might be what you're looking for:

http://developers.box.com/docs/#shared-items-get-a-shared-item

To quote:

> Once the item has been retrieved, you can make API requests against
>   the actual resource (/files/{id} or /folders/{id} as long as the
>   shared link and optional password are in the header.

Comment: The web_link is not shared yet, so I don't have the shared link for it. Actually I was trying to share it via the API.
Anyway, the problem is that I can't access the resource with /files/{id}, maybe because it isn't a file. One way or the other, the problem remains...

Comment: Looks like support for web_links was broken even further.<br/> Now even the shared_link is not returned when requested with get_folder_contents